# Do strong objects get destroyed on segue?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, memory-management, segue

I have a iPhone app with a table view and an add button in the navigation bar. The table view has a custom `NSObject` that holds it's data called `dataBase`. `dataBase` is a `(strong, nonatomic) @property` of this table view. The table view has a public method that allows new data to be added to `dataBase`. On clicking the add button there is a segue to a new view that lets you set the same of the new cell. On hitting a save button another segue is used to call the public method adding the information to `dataBase`. However, the original `dataBase` object is gone when this second segue is called, meaning that there is only ever one item in `dataBase`. Is this to be expected with segues? In order to keep the object alive do I need to pass the object itself around?

Sorry if this is a very noob question, I'm new to iOS programming and reference counting memory management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with a segue, so don't confuse the issue for yourself.

The basic deal with reference counted objects is that as long as there is at least one reference to the object, it will not be deallocated.  However, once the reference count reaches zero, the object will be deallocated.

So, if you want an object to be kept "alive" then you need to keep a reference to it in some way.  If you expect your database to be around for the life of the program, the usual pattern is to use a "singleton" object.  This can be accomplished in many ways.  A simple way is to mimic the common singleton pattern:

```
@interface Database : NSObject
    + (Database*)sharedInstance;
    // other stuff for your class
@end

@implementation Database
    + (Database*)sharedInstance {
        static Database *instance;
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            instance = [[Foo alloc] init];
            // Any other initialization necessary...
        });
        return instance;
    }
@end
```

The `dispatch_once` stuff ensures correctness for multi-threaded applications (which **all** iOS apps should be).

Now, when you need your "shared" `Database` object...

```
Database *database = [Database sharedInstance];
```

The `dispatch_once` code, in addition to making it thread-safe, will make sure the creation code runs exactly once.  The static object inside the function will keep a reference to the object, so it will never be deallocated... and live for the entire life of the program.

This is one common pattern for dealing with this situation, but there are many others.  The key is that if you want an object to live, you have to keep a reference to it.  Pass it to each view controller, or keep it in a "common" place, or archive it to disk when not needed, and re-hydrate it later when it is needed...  lots of ways to do it...

Comment: Thanks for the information. I thought the segue was removing references to the object but this is not the case. Thank you for the singleton suggestion, I'll look into using one for my app. As a follow up question, are there any is there any reason to just pass around this database object as opposed to making it a singleton (ie. why are singletons the way to go)? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Singletons are not necessarily the way to go.  You should decide what is more appropriate for your situation.  However, a good case for using a singleton will be a single object that lives for the whole program, and is used in multiple places.  Sometimes it makes for cleaner, more maintainable code to do it that way.